# SQL - need to merge text from duplicate entries, eliminate the duplicates

Tags: sql, concatenation, ms-access-2013

I have a table in Access that is (roughly) like this:

```
Name|Description|DocumentNo
Jim|ABCDEFG|1
John|HIJKLMNO|2
Fred|PQRS|2
Jim|TUV|3
Fred|WXYZ|4
John|AABBCC|4
```

We're going to import the descriptions into a different database. The names column is unimportant here, but what IS important is capturing all of the description text along with each document number.

What I need to do is, wherever there's an entry where the Document number values are duplicative, to merge them into one single entry.  E.g, like this:

```
Description|DocumentNo
ABCDEFG|1
HIJKLMNO; PQRS|2
TUV|3
WYXZ;AABBCC|4
```

This will clearly have a couple of steps; can someone point me in the right direction? Didn't see anything with this exact question elsewhere.... I have everything united in one table, and can identify the dupes easily enough, but I am not sure how to go about doing this using SQL in Access. (Would it be better to just use =CONCATENATE in Excel to handle this?)

Comment: when you say ControlNo values, are you referring to DocumentNo values?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I'll fix that.

Comment: If you want to do it in Access, take a look at some of previous SO posts about [ConcatRelated](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+concatrelated)

Comment: shouldn't docNo 4 be combined as well?

Comment: Yes, it should. Fixed, too. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @HansUp - the function posted at allenbrowne.com was exactly what I needed. It allows a simple query to concatenate all results of a specified field when the criteria is met (e.g., as it my example, I was able to use it to concatenate the 'description' field when the 'documentno' field was duplicative.

Link is here - along with everything needed to get started if you have a problem similar to the one I described above:  http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Query I used was:

```
SELECT [DocumentNo], ConcatRelated("[Description]","[TableName]","[DocumentNo] = " & [DocumentNo]) AS [Description] FROM [TableName];
```